# From where i can download jwplayer.js

Tags: javascript, video-player, jwplayer7

I am not getting a  location from where i can download the jwplayer.js . I searched on the google and found  solution at the support to download the jwplayer.js from  [https://account.jwplayer.com/#/account](https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/#/account) but  i did not found any thing here. it is just showing my profile information.

Comment: You need player or .js file?

Comment: .js file which import player in  my html page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Login to the [jwplayer.com][1]
2. Go the **Player** option on the right hand.
3. Select the option **Manage**
4. Click on the **Title of option** of any of your choice either **16:9** or **480*270**
5. You will redirect to page  with detail of player and then click on the bottom option of the right hand option "Player Library URL".
6. Copy that JS url and use in your page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxb1o.png)

OR You can download Directly From

http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/NxsmWX2o.js

Comment: It's ridiculous how hard they made downloading a simple js file :)

Comment: its not hard @M--. Secondly it is like this because one library file is according to customization settings you do in your account. You may change that settings in your account later and your library file link will have all those customization. It's wonderful.

Comment: @Simer please.  It is intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: this is version 7.12.11